# problem when trying to save file by notepad++ : "the previous version of the file could not be saved into the backup directory ..."?

Tags: notepad++

I am meeting a problem when using notepad++.
Here is my problem. I changed something in my file, and tried to save it by notepad++. It said to me File Backup Failed and here is my error as you can see in this picture
[image: picture about my problem]

It said to me that The previous version of the file could not be saved into the backup directory at ...

I reference this link https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20248/the-previous-version-of-the-file-cannot-be-saved-notepad-error-popup

And tried to change the file name, make it to be shorten, as it said, but nothing change.

How can I solve this problem ? Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Change your preferences from the Settings tab in Notepad++.  Click the Backup option from the list and click none for Backup on Save.
I also unchecked "Enable session snapshot and periodic backup"

[image: Settings]